# How do I remove an object from the GUI class?

Tags: esenthel-engine

In the Esenthel engine, you can easily add an object like a button to your GUI class with `Gui += buttonInstance.create("click on me")`, but I'm just wondering how can you remove an on object from from GUI members.

As far as I have found, there is no such a method as `removeChild` or `getChildren`, or anything similar.

Comment: And before/after you downvote I really recommend you take a look at this engine! It's the most easy to prototype engine I've ever seen! and it's free to evaluate.

Comment: Have you checked the docs?

Comment: not recently, I was working with this engine around 9 months ago and that time I just skiped removing object from GUI, just made them invisible I can do the same thing again, but i'm just looking for some better replacement to that.

Comment: Then check the docs.

Comment: I see this question is old, but your still active, so I thought I would throw my 2 cents in. This question shows no research effort, in that you already tell us you know where to go for the answer, but feel you wanted to *advertise* the engine. You could still have raised awareness, through this very question. By finding the answer, yourself, you can post a question with a self-answer. As you can see, I have retagged your question with a tag created for the engine, where we can provide guidance for the tag and point users to references, for example.

Comment: As per the answer; your entirely allowed to provide your own answer. In the below answer, you appear to have provided the answer for the point of accepting it. I would actually *downvoted* (given that you note the answer does not work at all, and the answerer notes that it is *just speculation*), and provided my own answer,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, seeing as you use the += operator to add a button, perhaps you use the -= operator to remove one? So something like the following *pseudocode*:

```
mybutton = buttonInstance.create("click on me")
Gui += mybutton
// when it comes time to remove the button...
Gui -= mybutton
```

I'm just speculating here, but I would be surprised to find otherwise, because it would strike me as inconsistent for `+` to add but `-` not to remove.

---

According to Gajet in the comments, `Gui.desktop()->removeChild(mybutton)` is the proper code to remove a GUI element.

Comment: no there is no `-=` opreator implemented but when i looked for that operator I saw there was the implementatoin on `+=` there. I'm not sure if it's correct but it's how i'm managing to remove objects from Gui `Gui.desktop()->removeChild(myButton)`. I guess technicaly you have to get my accept (since your answer gave me the idea to have deep look into header file) but you need to edit your answer before first!

Comment: I'm glad you found it! Now file a bug report and ask for the `-=` operator to be implemented. :)

Comment: I am downvoting on the basis that this answer is mostly speculation that has been confirmed as incorrect. Ideally, the incorrect speculations should have been removed in favour of the corrections, instead of adding the corrections as an after note. *Ideally*, the asker would have posted their own answer to this, as it appears entirely from their own research and post.